# Where in real applications is a need for sorting numbers

Tags: sorting, numbers

Can anyone give some important/often used examples where there is a need for sorting (a large amount of )numbers in real applications Edit: Basically i thought of not so obvious places where sorting occurs but is not really evident to a user. So what my question should have been is i think, where does sorting occur where one does not expect it.

Comment: I think I have *never* written a non-trivial application where I *didn’t* need sorting at some point.

Answer (score 7):

Any time you show the user a grid and allow them to sort based on a numeric column.

A good example would be the fact that eBay allows you to sort listings by the current Bid amount. If you're viewing a large number of listings, you're going to have to sort through quite a bit of data.

You could also simply look at the site you're on. Go back to the Questions page here on StackOverflow and sort on 'Votes'. You just performed a sort on a dataset of 1.9 million numbers.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by a real application?

What about a sales management tool? You always need sorting to find out the best performing products, the ones that are running out of stock, etc

Comment: Finding "the best" is a different problem (finding the max). It is also much easier than sorting.

Answer (score 2):

**This site. Sort by Views, answers, etc etc.**

Standings for sports. (Sorted by wins, losses)

Stats - Group players based on HRs, RBIs, AVG.

The list goes on and on

Answer (score 2):

Computing the median of a statistical sample. Permitting fast searching of a set of records indexed numerically. Also, human beings like looking at ordered sets of data, and as such sorting can be useful at the level of presentation.

Note: finding the minimum and maximum, while common and important operations, do not require sorting. Lots of operations that may seem to require sorting do not... so you should be sure that what you're doing really requires sorting before you commit to sorting data.

Answer (score 1):

Age of an object is a common use. Lots of views/processes want to show/use the oldest first to prioritize work on something.

Sports scores are often organized with respect to the team that has the largest win/loss ratio.

Answer (score 1):

In invoices and reports you sometimes need to show items that have the highest quantities on the top of a list such as a sales report or something... but there are database ORDER BY clauses, and wizardy controls for that sort of thing usually... the only place you really need to implement your own sort algorithms is when you are trying to sort objects in memory that perhaps have one or two numeric properties that need to be sorted.

The only real life example In which I've actually had to numerically sort objects that I can think of had to do with these wall-readers for reading barcodes on plastic cards... the service allowing them to communicate with the database had to constantly run checks to ensure that they were all still online and had to constantly report statistics on which readers were performing the worst, which ones got the most/least user activity, etc...